# Use my own styles with 3rd party React.js component libraries

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI as a component library in my React project. I want to use the functionality of the components but use my own styles that I have written over the year. Since Material UI comes with its own inline styling, that overrides my styles, can I somehow control the styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but since you mention inline styles, it sounds like you are using v0.x. If so, you would have to override the default styles with `!important`.

With v1.0 there is much more more flexibility, as it uses CSS classes that you can more easily override, either using the `className` prop to affect the root component, or the `classes` prop to target multiple classes.

The classes you can override are listed in the API docs.

Comment: Well yeah I am aware that I can override the styles with !important tags but i dont wanna do that all around the application. 

You are correct that Im using v0.x. I wasn't aware v1.0 comes with a different approach. I think I am going to research on that. 

Thanks!